# C# OWIN OAuth2 Server: Access token always returns invalid_grant

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, authorization, owin

I am building an OAuth2 Authorization Server as per this example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server

I have an authorization code and am attempting to exchange it for an access token. No matter what, I get a 400 response "invalid_grant".

Here's my relevant server implementation:

```
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions serverOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString(authorizePath),
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString(tokenPath),
            ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true,
            AllowInsecureHttp = true, // tsk tsk

            Provider = new OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
            {
                //OnValidateAuthorizeRequest = ValidateAuth,
                OnValidateClientRedirectUri = ValidateClientRedirectUri,
                OnValidateClientAuthentication = ValidateClientAuthentication,
                OnGrantResourceOwnerCredentials = GrantResourceOwnerCredentials,
                OnGrantClientCredentials = GrantClientCredetails
            },
            // Authorization code provider which creates and receives authorization code
            AuthorizationCodeProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider
            {
                OnCreate = CreateAuthenticationCode,
                OnReceive = ReceiveAuthenticationCode
            },

            // Refresh token provider which creates and receives referesh token
            RefreshTokenProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider
            {
                OnCreate = CreateRefreshToken,
                OnReceive = ReceiveRefreshToken,
            }
        };

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(serverOptions);

    private Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
    {
        context.Validated(context.RedirectUri);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        string clientId;
        string clientSecret;
        if (context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret) ||
            context.TryGetFormCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret))
        {
            context.Validated();
        }
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }


    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _authenticationCodes =
       new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.Ordinal);
    private void CreateAuthenticationCode(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        context.SetToken(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n") + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n"));
        _authenticationCodes[context.Token] = context.SerializeTicket();
    }

    private void ReceiveAuthenticationCode(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        string value;

        if (_authenticationCodes.TryRemove(context.Token, out value))
        {
            context.DeserializeTicket(value);
        }
        context.DeserializeTicket(value);
    }

    private void CreateRefreshToken(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        context.SetToken(context.SerializeTicket());
    }

    private void ReceiveRefreshToken(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        context.DeserializeTicket(context.Token);
    }
```

And here's where I request the token in the client:

```
            var requestPrefix = Request.Scheme + "://" + Request.Host;
        var redirectUri = requestPrefix + Request.PathBase + Options.CallbackPath + "/";

        var body = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", code),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", redirectUri),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", Options.ClientId),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", Options.ClientSecret),

            };

        HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var tokenResponse =
            await _httpClient.PostAsync(Constants.GARBAGE_TOKEN, new FormUrlEncodedContent(body));

        var text = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

What I've tested so far:

- I've added breakpoints in all of those provider functions and added context.Validated everywhere I could. Previously, it was not hitting ReceiveAuthenticationCode because the context was not being validated in the ValidateClientAuthentication. This made me assume I was missing a validation step somewhere, but I can't find anywhere else.
- Now it does reach ReceiveAuthenticationCode, gets the token, and deserializes the ticket. Context.Identity.Ticket isn't null and has data so I assume it is correct anyway.

But after that - I lose track of it. It comes back to the calling client as "invalid_grant" and I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out where in the pipeline the token goes next. Presumably, some provider element is being invoked which sets the token to invalid for some reason, but I've been pouring over the OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider source and I've got nothing and there doesn't seem to be any way to step through it. In fact, even knowing the part of the code that handles the actual response of sending out the token would be useful; that is all opaque to me.

Why is the token being invalidated? Is it actually being invalidated or is some other error causing it to return invalid_grant? How do I get eyes on this part?

I have also looked through the microsoft doc example on creating an OAuth2 server linked at the start, which most of this is based on. It however is no help, because it uses this helper method which encapsulated everything:

```
var authorizationState = _webServerClient.ProcessUserAuthorization(Request);
```

So that doesn't tell me much, and I am also unsure about exactly how the above helper works, since it appears to handle the auth code submission and token request all in one.

Comment: May I ask how you retrieve the authorization code in the first place from your CreateAuthenticationCode method? Is there a format to follow?

Comment: Did you resolve the issue in the end? I'm stuck on the exact same bit

Answer (score 0):

You can enable OWIN tracing to possibly get a more descriptive error message.

Add this to your app.config:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
        <add name="Microsoft.Owin" value="All" />
    </switches>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="file" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="OWINtrace.log" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <sources>
        <source name="Microsoft.Owin" switchName="Microsoft.Owin" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
            <listeners>
                <add name="file" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

After reproducing the problem, examine OWINtrace.log. It should be in the folder with your executeable.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a `POST` request when requesting access token.